# How do you check if a list's item is equal to another item in the same list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I understand the basics of this problem however I need help on how I can do this the most efficient way possible (taking the least amount of time for the programmer however not substituting stability of the code or efficiency).

Let's say we have a string:

```
grades=str(input("Enter a string"))
```

in my code, I would join a space between all characters in the string above and then split the characters into separate items in the same list:

```
grades=" ".join(grades)
grades.split(" ")
```

I then want to use loops of some sort to search the list for repeating items. However, I want to learn how I can do this the most efficient way possible:

```
x=len(grades)
for i in range(0, x):
    if grades[i] ==  # here is were I'm having trouble
```

I want to know how I can search whether 1 item in the list is equal to any item in the whole list itself. Kind regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I make an example:

```
from collections import Counter

a =[1,2,3,4,1,2]
c = Counter(a)
for k,v in c.items():
    if v>1:
        print(k,'repeated more than once')
```

Here the `c` will be a Counter object like this `Counter({1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 1})`. the keys are the array values and values are the count of them. 
So I write the `for` for your understanding. You can do anything with `c`, it acts like a `dict`.

```
 >> [k for k,v in c.items() if v>1]
 [1, 2]
```

Comment: Thank you however once tested I found an error, it is much easier if you do not use both k and v in the 4th line of code. You can just use k or v, not both.

Comment: I get `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable` for the line: `for k,v in c:`.

Comment: sorry I forgot `.items()`. it is fixed now.@quamrana